# Debugging code with loop not working correctly

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm writing a Gauss elimination process for a matrix. I cant use hard coded values. The start address of the matrix is in a0 and the N bytes are in $a1.
Here is the code I have written for this function:
Edit: I commited a change and now only one value is wrong.
Edit: The only value that is wrong in my results is the -1.05 in the last column second row

```
t0 = k address of matrix
t5 = B = 4*N
t9 = (N^2 * 4) - 4 (Offset of last element)
t6 = C = N - 1
f15 = 1
f16 = 0
    L1:         
        beq $t0, $t9, out               # branch out if k > last elem
        nop
            #swc1 $f15, 0($t0)              # 1.00 -> A[k][k]
        
        addi $t1, $t0, 4                # j = k+1   
        add $t2, $t0, $t5               # i = k + B

        sll $t3, $t6, 2                 # temp1 = C*4
        add $t7, $t0, $t3               # c_check = k + (C*4)
        
        subi $t4, $t6, 1                # temp2 = C-1
        nop
        mul $t4, $t4, $t5               # temp2 = (C-1)*B
        nop
        add $t8, $t2, $t4               # r_check = i + B
            
        lwc1 $f0, 0($t0)                # f0 = A[k][k]  
        nop
        div.s $f0, $f15, $f0                # f0 = 1 / A[k][k]                      
    L2:  
        lwc1 $f1, 0($t1)                # f1 = A[k][j]  
        nop
        #div.s $f2, $f1, $f0                # f2 = A[k][j] / A[k}[k]
        mul.s $f2, $f1, $f0             # f2 = A[k][j] * 1 / A[k][k]
        nop
        swc1 $f2, 0($t1)                # f2 -> A[k][j] 
        
        bne $t1, $t7, L2                # branch to L2 if we're not in last column
        addi $t1, $t1, 4                # j++           
        
        swc1 $f15, 0($t0)               # 1.00 -> A[k][k] 
        # PIVOT LOOP
    L3: 
        add $t7, $t2, $t3               # c_check = i + (C*4)
        addi $t1, $t2, 4                # j = i+1
        lwc1 $f0, 0($t2)                # f0 = A[i][k]
          #addi $t4, $t0, 4             # temp2 = A[k][j]
    L4:     
        nop
        lwc1 $f1, 0($t1)                #f1 = A[i][j]   
        sub $t4, $t1, $t5               #temp2 = A[k][j] (ADDRESS) A[i][j] - B
        nop
        lwc1 $f2, 0($t4)                #f2 = A[k][j]
        nop
        mul.s $f30, $f2, $f0                #f0 = A[k][j] * A[i][k]
        nop
        sub.s $f1, $f1, $f30                #f1 = A[i][j] - (A[k][j] * A[i][k])
        nop
        swc1   $f1, 0($t1)              #f1 -> A[i][j]
        
        #addi $t4, $t4, 4               # temp2++
        bne $t1, $t7, L4                # j<=c_check     branch out of L4 if we're in last column
        addi $t1, $t1, 4                # j++                   # Increase r-pointer to next row
        
        swc1 $f16, 0($t2)               # A[i][k] = 0.0
        bne $t2, $t8, L3                # i<r_check branch to L3 if we're not on last row
        add $t2, $t2, $t5               # i++
        
        subi $t6, $t6, 1                # C--
        
        addi $t3, $t5, 4                # temp1 = next diagonal element in matrix
        
            #beq $t0, $t9, out              # branch to out if last elem of matrix
            #add $t0, $t0, $t3              # k++
        
        jal L1                      # jump to L1
        add $t0, $t0, $t3               # k++   
    
    
    
    out:    
        swc1 $f15, 0($t0)               # 1.00 -> A[k][k]
```

I have inserted two pictures of actual results vs mine, what is causing this error?

[image: Actual results]

[[image: My reuslts - improved2]

Comment: FP rounding error explains most of your values.  Only the -0.41 looks wrong in the bottom right, just above the diagonal.  I'd recommend checking for off-by-one errors in your looping, single-stepping with a debugger to see if you're loading a wrong value from somewhere.

Comment: I should have added it in the description, all are correct except the -0.41. I have checked the loops and done single stepping and it was all correct. It's all very weird to me because all calculations get executed right except that one

Comment: Check the input to see if it is right.

Comment: @ErikEidt I did that, Can there be something that my inputs are floats and one of my registers are not set for that?

Comment: Do you have a working C version of this? If so, annotate with printf's at every assignment to the float array. Do the same with the assembly version. Then run both with the same input, and compare the output streams.

Comment: I debugged it using the MIPS code and did the calculations myself, it seems that there is a rounding error that has occurred. I tried substituting instructions that operate on $f with .s instructions but it did not help.